# Request access on site collection

Tags: permissions

I am building some community site collection. All users will have read permissions. Some group of users will have contribute permissions. Is it possible to build something in SharePoint where visitors can request contribute permissions? It is like some visitor will register he's self in some community. And will collaborate with the other community members.

Comment: are you using SP on prem or in O365?

Comment: I am using o365

Comment: Most of this functionality is already built into the site - example: Add allusers group as visitors -they can then make a request to "join the community" via the  "join this community" button or clicking on the new discussion button. Site admins can approve their access. Auto approval can also be set to speed up users joining the community

Comment: I give everybody read permissions. But how they can do the request "join this community"? I used the template "team site" for this community site.

Comment: try using the community site template instead of the team site template